# Does "into" mean only "from outside to inside "?

Tags: prepositions

> The device generates clean air and discharges it into the room.

Could the sentence above only be interpreted as the device being located outside the room?

I don't want to eliminate the possibility that the device is located inside the room.

Comment: No, because the air is discharged from the device. Your sentence does not imply that the device is located anywhere in particular.

Comment: There might be a pipe or duct that runs through a wall. It says nothing about where it is. Also, I don't much like "discharge" here.

Comment: *Into* is used to indicated that something has moved from container A to container B.   *The cat jumped out of the box into the room.  We stepped out of the subway car and into the station.*  Even though the box and subway car are contained by the larger room and station, you still move *into* the larger container from the smaller and vice versa.

Comment: air is not discharged here. **Air is released**

Comment: The air is released from the device into the room. We have no idea where the air comes from, or where the device is located.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most readers would not think your sentence eliminates the possibility of the device being inside the room. Most people would think that the air "in the device" is not "in the room" even though the device is in the room.

For example "I hid the gift in the drawer, but when the party started I brought it out into the room."

Comment: It says nothing about the location of the device, just what it does. There are devices that recycle air in a room. So....

Comment: You know, I am coming back here to this as I received 6 negative votes, and I simply cannot understand it. Then, my answer was deleted by the mod! Meanwhile, as I reread your answer, I see that you say that the "air" is not "in the room". The air presumably goes through the device and is released into the room. I assume this is about air purification, don't you? The source of the air can be from the outside (of the building) through a duct or it can be sucked in from inside the building and purified and released. I am stumped by the reaction to my post. :) Any ideas?

Comment: @Lambie This literally all I see to this post...I cannot see your deleted answer. I don't even have 1K rep here

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine Ok, no problem.

Answer (score -6):

The device generates clean air and **releases it** into the room. **release**, not discharge.

IMPROVEMENT. :)

However, it does not say where the device is located.

For example:
The device works by sucking the air inside of it, where it goes through a filtration system to clean it. After filtration, the device releases clean air into the room.

[release air into the room](https://ionizerhub.com/homelabs-air-purifier-review/)

Air passes through the filter, which removes the pollutants and releases clean air into the room. For the ionization air purifiers, the process does not use physical filters and instead relies on charged particles (ions) to trap the contaminants.

[release clean air into the room](https://wezaggle.com/air-scrubber-vs-air-purifier/)

"into" means from one space (outside a building) into the building or room. However, AC units can be in a number of places but they all draw air from the outside INTO the space to be cooled.

Comment: Woe to downvoters.

Comment: 1. This doesn't answer the asker's question. The question was does the original sentence *eliminate the possibility* that the device is within the room.  DJClayworth more clearly illustrates that no, it does not.  2. The word "discharge" is acceptable here.  Even so, if you have a reason that the sentence should be changed, please specify.

Comment: @mjjf The original sentence is very poor. The question was: Could the sentence above only be interpreted as the device being located outside the room? Which I answered: **It does not say where the device is located**. The word discharge is awful here. The other answer does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133913/discussion-on-answer-by-lambie-does-into-mean-only-from-outside-to-inside).